# iOS error notification when upload to apple store finish

Tags: ios, iphone, cordova

I'm trying to make `iOS` apps using `phonegap`, but when I finish upload to the apple store, all going well I just got an email notification with error :

`Version Mismatch - Neither CFBundleVersion ['2.0.0'] nor CFBundleShortVersionString [''] in the Info.plist match the version of the app set in iTunes Connect ['2.0'].`

What causes this error? Is there anything wrong in the config.xml settings in phonegap?

My config.xml :

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<widget id="com.joriscorp.xxxx" version="2.0.0" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:gap="http://phonegap.com/ns/1.0">
    <name>Baca Berita</name>
    <description>
        Aplikasi android untuk mendapatkan informasi terkini dari situs www.bacaberita.com.
    </description>
    <author email="bertho_joris@yahoo.co.id" href="http://www.berthojoris.com/">
        Bertho Joris
    </author>
    <feature name="http://api.phonegap.com/1.0/device" />
    <preference name="phonegap-version" value="3.3.0" />
    <preference name="permissions" value="none" />
    <preference name="orientation" value="portrait" />
    <preference name="target-device" value="universal" />
    <preference name="fullscreen" value="false" />
    <preference name="webviewbounce" value="true" />
    <preference name="prerendered-icon" value="true" />
    <preference name="stay-in-webview" value="false" />
    <preference name="detect-data-types" value="true" />
    <preference name="exit-on-suspend" value="false" />
    <preference name="show-splash-screen-spinner" value="true" />
    <preference name="auto-hide-splash-screen" value="true" />
    <preference name="disable-cursor" value="false" />
    <preference name="ios-statusbarstyle" value="black-opaque" />
    <icon src="icon.png" />
    <icon src="icons/ios/icon.png" gap:platform="ios" width="57" height="57" />
    <icon src="icons/ios/icon-72.png" gap:platform="ios" width="72" height="72" />
    <icon src="icons/ios/icon_at_2x.png" gap:platform="ios" width="114" height="114" />
    <icon src="icons/ios/icon-72_at_2x.png" gap:platform="ios" width="144" height="144" />
    <gap:splash src="splash/ios/Default.png" gap:platform="ios" width="320" height="480" />
    <gap:splash src="splash/ios/Default_at_2x.png" gap:platform="ios" width="640" height="960" />
    <gap:splash src="splash/ios/Default_iphone5.png" gap:platform="ios" width="640" height="1136" />
    <gap:splash src="splash/ios/Default-Landscape.png" gap:platform="ios" width="1024" height="748" />
    <gap:splash src="splash/ios/Default-Portrait.png" gap:platform="ios" width="768" height="1004" />
    <gap:splash src="splash/ios/Default-Landscape_at_2x.png" gap:platform="ios" width="2048" height="1496" />
    <gap:splash src="splash/ios/Default-Portrait_at_2x.png" gap:platform="ios" width="1536" height="2008" />
    <access origin="*" />
</widget>
```

What should I do to handle this error?

Thanks....

Comment: They are saying that in iTunes connect you set the version as `2.0` and in your config.xml you have it set as `2.0.0`. You need to make them match. Either change it in itunes connect or change it in your config.xml, but they need to match exactly

Answer (score 0):

According to the email, it seems as if you need to change your Version number in the General section of your Target from "2.0.0" to "2.0" and your Bundle version string in your Info.plist from " " to "2.0" since "2.0" is the version listed in iTunes Connect.

This line, for example, should be:

```
<widget id="com.joriscorp.xxxx" version="2.0" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:gap="http://phonegap.com/ns/1.0">
```